# if文でエラーが起こりました。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ナビゲーションバーで通知を未確認なら「未確認通知」確認済みなら「通知」とだけ表示して、未確認通知がある際にしっかりと未確認通知の表示が行われるように確認をしようとしたのですが、if文の箇所でエラーが起きました。

applications/_navbar.html.erb

```
<% if Notification.checked == false %>
                <li class="ms-3"><%= link_to '未確認の通知', notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav'%></li>
              <% else %>
                <li class="ms-3"><%= link_to '通知', notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav' %></li>
              <% end %>
```

エラー文

```
NoMethodError in Toppages#index
Showing /home/ubuntu/environment/test01/app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb where line #23 raised:

undefined method `checked' for Notification:Class
Extracted source (around line #23):
              
              <li class="ms-3"><%= link_to 'TOP', '/', class: 'nav-link plan-nav' %></li>
              <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <% if Notification.checked == false %>　←エラー箇所
                <li class="ms-3"><%= link_to '未確認の通知', notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav'%></li>
              <% else %>
                <li class="ms-3"><%= link_to '通知', notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav' %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

通知ボタンを表示するコントローラーで通知テーブルから自分に届いているcheckdeがfalseのデータを取り出して、if文で存在していたら未確認の通知を。
無かった場合は普通の通知ボタンを表示させることで解決しました。